# Docker 1.9.1 - ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: mysql, django, docker

We have a two docker setup, one is running a django app and the other running MySQL. Earlier we were using docker 1.8.3 and everything was working fine, after upgrading to 1.9.1 we are facing this issue.

We are creating a MySQL docker:

```
docker run --name <mysql docker name> -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD={} -d mysql:5.5.44
```

Next we are running a batchfile, which is nothing but creating a DB, granting access to the user

```
docker run -it --rm -v <setup_file>:/mnt mysql:5.5.44 sh -c 'exec mysql -h"<db server name>" -P"3306" -uroot -p"<password>" < /mnt/batchfile'
```

Next we are creating the django docker

```
docker run --name <django server name> --link <db server name> -it --rm ubuntu /bin/bash
```

When the django docker comes up we get the error message

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host <DB server> (0)
```

Is there any additional parameter that we need to send for docker 1.9.1?

Comment: Is `<mysql docker name>` the same as `<db server name>`?

Comment: Yes, my bad. <mysql docker name> and <db server name> are same.